# Ruby regular expressions and substrings

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm in trouble with these kind of strings:

```
1) 125******* or 125co****** or 125CO*******
2) 125af***** or 125AF****** or 125f****** or 125AF********
```

The initial number's length can be between 2 and 11 chars, followed by some substrings (such as "co", "f", etc) and then by alphanumeric strings.

For now I made these two regex, but they don't work properly:

```
/^([0-9]{2,11})([c]?[o]?)/i
/^([0-9]{2,11})(a?)f/i
```

Note that both situations should not conflict themselves.
1) and 2) are separate.
How can I do?

**edit: added from comment:**

I've added more informations to explain. Through an admin panel, the user can upload files, and the system should save them into proper directories, based on their names.

Eg. a file called

```
125.doc or 
125co_tes.doc or 
125CO_tes.doc
```

should be saved into "collection" directory,
but the ones called

```
125af.double.jpg or 
125AF-happy.txt or 
125f_testlong.xls or 
125AF.pdf
```

should be saved into "documents" directory, and so on.

Comment: I've added more informations to explain. Through an admin panel, the user can upload files, and the system should save them into proper directories, based on their names. Eg. a file called "125.doc or 125co_tes.doc or 125CO_tes.doc" should be saved into "collection" directory, but the ones called "125af.double.jpg or 125AF-happy.txt or 125f_testlong.xls or 125AF.pdf" should be saved into "documents" directory, and so on.

Comment: What about your two Regexps doesn't work properly?

Comment: As explained below, those two Regexps were in conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching files for "collection":

```
/^(\d{2,11})((?:(?:c?o|co?).*)?\.[a-z0-9]+)$/i
```

Matching files for "documents":

```
/^(\d{2,11})((?:af?|a?f).+)$/i
```

Let me know if it's not strict enough (or too strict) for your application.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having problems: your regex ^(\d{2,11}[Aa]?[Ff]?.+)$  matches files called "125CO.pdf" and this is wrong. They should not conflict each other.

Comment: @MichDart: I apologize for not checking this beforehand, it slipped my mind. I've revised the answer to fix the issues you were having.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I have modified a little the first regex. Here is:     ^(\d{2,11})((?:[Cc][Oo]?|[Cc]?[Oo]).+)$ Bye!

Comment: @MichDart: I think your modification will make it not able to match 125.doc - but if that is what you want, happy I could help. Consider accepting my answer if this solved it for you.

Comment: Yes, you're right! But that regex also matches this:  "125af.doc" =~ /^(\d{2,11})([Cc]?[Oo]?.*)$/i    and should not! I appreciate your help

Comment: @MichDart: Good call. Revised my answer once again to fix this. Also removed redundant checks for upper and lower case letters.

Comment: How about if I remove .doc? /^(\d{2,11})((?:(?:c?o|co?).*)?)$/i, matches again "125af.doc" and shouldn't

Comment: @MichDart: Do you need it to match other filetypes than .doc?

Comment: @MichDart: Ok, revised answer once again.

Comment: Awesome! Sorry, but I can't Vote up (low reputation)

Answer (score 1):

```
string="125af.double.jpg"
case string
  when /^([0-9]{2,11})(a?)f/i
    # Document
  when /^([0-9]{2,11})([c]?[o]?)/i
    # Collection
end
```

If you check `/^([0-9]{2,11})(a?)f/i` first there's no conflict between the 2 regexps.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a more maintainable solution! But this works great!

Answer (score 0):

With the following, you can test both file types

```
if filename =~ /^\d{2,11}(co|a?f)?/i 
  if $1 == '' || $1.downcase == 'co'
     # do CO
  elsif $1.downcase == 'af'
     # do AF
  end
end
```

See in action http://rubular.com/r/7jGxQVJMNC

It will certainly be difficult to maintain if you have more 2 cases...

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a more maintainable solution! But this works great!